# Using PHP how can I find a CSS tag/id/class and replace the style within the curly braces?

Tags: php, css, regex, preg-match

I need to traverse through a CSS file finding specific items and changing their CSS to updated stuff for a theme editor. I have a variable with all the CSS for between the curly braces, I just need to find a way to select the braces after the given tag and replace the contents. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks

Comment: Why not add new CSS definitions at the bottom of the file? I am sure you can overwrite existing definitions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe not the only solution, but have you thought about putting the CSS into the database and generate the CSS file on the fly?

Storing it in the database also gives you the possibility to re-generate the file every time somethings changed and have it cached like that to save performance.

To modify an existing file you probably need to traverse through the file and hope that nobody manually changes the style conventions for your CSS-file and replace as you go along by remembering the last tag/class/id expression like that (will probably not work out of the box!):

```
$newFileContent = "";
$searchClass = "td.content";
$lines = file("style.css");
$insideSearchedTag = false;
foreach($lines as $line) {
  if (strstr($line, $searchClass) !== false) {
    $insideSearchedTag = true;
    $newFileContent .= "\n" . $line;
  }
  else if (strstr($line, "}") !== false) {
    $insideSearchedTag = false;
    $newFileContent .= "\n" . $line;
  }
  else if ($insideSearchedTag) {
    // search/replace the content you want to replace.
    $newLineContent = str_ireplace($searchStyle, $replaceStyle, $line);
    $newFileContent .= "\n" . $newLineContent;
  }
  else { $newFileContent .= "\n" . $line; }
}
fwrite($file, $newFileContent);
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your comment, I am not allowed to alter the current css system unfortunately. I have to leave the existing css file and edit it

Comment: Then obviously you need to traverse the file, read it line by line and search for the tag/id/class you're looking for. Then search for the style information you want to alter and replace what you need. The tag/id/class ends whenever there is a `}`

Comment: Do you know how to go line by line and then replace between the brackets?

Comment: Added some code snippets, which should show you a way to do it. But depending on the complexity and style-guide of your CSS file, you need to adapt.